# How to get file information within directory in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to get the file information within directory in MVC application.

Below is my code which gets me file names but I also want the file created dates and file size,

```
if (Directory.Exists(path))
{
    files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                                     .Select(Path.GetFileName).ToArray();
}
```

How do I do that?

Comment: Have a look at [FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: btw, this question has nothing to do with MVC

Comment: I've added an answer with code similar to what you are using, but instead of Path.GetFileName I used Select(f => new FileInfo(f))

Answer (score 2):

There isn't any method that provides the data you require for all files in  the directory.

You need to get this information for every file separately

```
foreach(var filename in file) {
   var fileInfo = new FileInfo(filename);
   var fileSize = fileInfo.Length;
   var fileCreated = fileInfo.CreationTime;
}
```

Comment: how about obtaining the company name from the file info?

Answer (score 1):

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Select(f => new FileInfo(f)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will most likely need to iterate around for files list and use the FileInfo class to get said info.

[Details on this class can be found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

Basically use a for/foreach loop and for each file name query the properties of an instantiated FileInfo class for things such as created date.